# Carbon Date startOfDay give me endOfDay date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
dd($dt->startOfDay(), $dt->endOfDay());

Carbon {#324 ▼
  +"date": "2017-05-15 23:59:59.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
}
Carbon {#324 ▼
  +"date": "2017-05-15 23:59:59.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
}
```

First variable is the date and hour actually, dd() function is for display content of variables.

**startOfDay()** method give me the same thing of the **endOfDay()** method...

Comment: Can you try:

`$dt = Carbon::now();
$dt2 = Carbon::now();
dd($dt->startOfDay(), $dt2->endOfDay());`

Just curious what the result will be.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Best practices to use `copy()` method for different date time.

```
$startDay = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$endDay   = $startDay->copy()->endOfDay();
```

To know more details :

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried to use `copy()` or assign to variable, and then use Carbon methods?

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
dd($dt->copy()->startOfDay(), $dt->copy()->endOfDay());
```

Don't change `$dt` value, only copy and then make `startOfDay()` or `endOfDay()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept one of the answers here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late, but someone might see this answer. The thing is when you use

```
dd($dt->startOfDay(), $dt->endOfDay());
```

it mutate $dt object that's why it shows both times as one. So make sure to copy it or clone it before use.

```
$dt->clone()->startOfDay();
$dt->clone()->endOfDay();
```